# Compute weighted averages for large numbers

Tags: java, average, weighted-average

I'm trying to get the weighted average of a few numbers. Basically I have:

```
Price    - 134.42
Quantity - 15236545
```

There can be as few as one or two or as many as fifty or sixty pairs of prices and quantities.  I need to figure out the weighted average of the price. Basically, the weighted average should give very little weight to pairs like

```
Price    - 100000000.00
Quantity - 3
```

and more to the pair above.

The formula I currently have is:

```
((price)(quantity) + (price)(quantity) + ...)/totalQuantity
```

So far I have this done:

```
        double optimalPrice = 0;
        int totalQuantity = 0;
        double rolling = 0;
        System.out.println(rolling);

        Iterator it = orders.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("inside");
            Map.Entry order = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            double price = (Double)order.getKey();
            int quantity = (Integer)order.getValue();
            System.out.println(price + " " + quantity);

            rolling += price * quantity;
            totalQuantity += quantity;
            System.out.println(rolling);
        }
        System.out.println(rolling);
        return rolling/totalQuantity;
```

The problem is I very quickly max out the "rolling" variable.

How can I actually get my weighted average?

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use `java.math.BigInteger` for both `rolling` and `totalQuantity`, and only divide them at the end. This has a better numeric stability, as you only have a single floating-point division at the end and everything else is integer operations.

`BigInteger` is basically unbounded so you shouldn't run into any overflows.

**EDIT:** Sorry, only upon re-reading I've noticed your price is a `double` anyway. Maybe it's worth circumventing this by multiplying it with 100 and then converting to `BigInteger` - since I see in your example it has precisely 2 digits right of the decimal point - and then divide it by 100 at the end, although it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: `1.055` -> `105`, you should add `0.005` to the value before multiplying by `100`, or `0.5` after the multiplying by `100` but before the integer conversion, such that: `1.055` -> `106`, which is the correct rounding.

Comment: @Pindatjuh: the idea is not to lose any precision at all. I suggested multiplying by 100 because it looks like the OP's prices have precisely two digits after the point, not more.

Comment: of course, but it wasn't criticism to your excellent suggestion (+1), just a note for better rounding when using the "hack" of multiplying by 100 and converting to an integer, in a case where there are more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 3):

A double can hold a pretty large number (about 1.7 x 10^308, according the docs), but you probably shouldn't use it for values where exact precision is required (such as monetary values).

Check out the [BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead. [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359817/java-bigdecimal) talks about it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

For maximum flexibility, use [`BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for `rolling`, and [`BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for `totalQuantity`.  After dividing (note, you have it backwards; it should be rolling / totalQuantity), you can either return a BigDecimal, or use [`doubleValue`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue%28%29) at a loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

At any given point, you have recorded both the total value `ax + by + cz + ... = pq` *and* the total weight `a + b + c + ... = p`.  Knowing both then gives you the average value `pq/p = q`.  The problem is that `pq` and `p` are large sums that overflow, even though you just want the moderately sized `q`.

The next step adds, for example, a weight of `r` and a value `s`.  You want to find the new sum `(pq + rs) / (p + r)` by using only the value of `q`, which can only happen if `p` and `pq` somehow "annihilate" by being in the numerator and denominator of the same fraction.  That's impossible, as I'll show.

The value that you need to add in this iteration is, naturally,

```
(pq + rs) / (p + r) - q
```

Which can't be simplified to a point where `p*q` and `p` disappear.  You can also find

```
(pq + rs) / q(p + r)
```

the factor by which you'd multiply q in order to get the next average; but again, `pq` and `p` remain.  So there's no clever solution.

Others have mentioned arbitrary-precision variables, and that's a good solution here.  The size of `p` and `pq` grow linearly with the number of entries, and the memory usage and calculation speed of integers/floats grows logarithmically with the size of the values.  So performance is O(log(n)) unlike the disaster that it would if `p` were somehow the multiple of many numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see how you could be "maxing out" the `rolling` variable.  As @Ash points out, it can represent values up to about `1.7 x 10^308`.  The only possibility I can think of is that you have some bad values in your input.  (Perhaps the real problem is that you are losing precision ...)

Second, your use of a `Map` as to represent orders is strange and probably broken.  The way you are currently using it, you cannot represent orders involving two or more items with the same price.

Comment: Yes, why not just store orders in a list?

Comment: A previous part of the program combines orders with the same price.

Answer (score 0):

Your final result is an just a weighted average of precises, so presumably you don't need to follow the rules used when calculating account balances etc. If I am correct about the above, then you don't need to use `BigDecimal`, `double` will suffice.

The problem of overflow can be solved by storing a "running average" and updating it with each new entry. Namely, let

a_n = (sum_{i=1}^n x_i * w_i) / (sum_{i=1}^n w_i)

for n = 1, ..., N. You start with a_n = x_n and then add

d_n := a_{n+1} - a_n

to it. The formula for d_n is

d_n = (x_{n+1} - w_{n+1}*a_n) / W_{n+1}

where W_n := sum_{i=1}^n w_n. You need to keep track of W_n, but this problem can be solved by storing it as `double` (it will be OK as we're only interested in the average). You can also normalize the weights, if you know that all your weights are multiples of 1000, just divide them by 1000.

To get additional accuracy, you can use [compensated summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Preemptive explanation: it is OK to use floating point arithmetic here. `double` has relative precision of 2E-16. The OP is averaging positive numbers, so there will be no cancellation error. What the proponents of arbitrary precision arithmetic don't tell you is that, leaving aside rounding rules, in the cases when it *does* give you lots of additional precision over IEEE754 floating point arithmetic, this will come at significant memory and performance cost. Floating point arithmetic was designed by very smart people (Prof. Kahan, among others), and if there was a way of cheaply increasing arithmetic precision over what is offered by floating point, they'd do it.

Disclaimer: if your weights are completely crazy (one is 1, another is 10000000), then I am not 100% sure if you will get satisfying accuracy, but you can test it on some example when you know what the answer should be.

Comment: You still have the problem that W_n increases in size with the number of (quantity,price) pairs.  But this may not be a problem with a maximum of 60 pairs.

Comment: Well it's probably not going to overflow `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Do two loops: compute totalQuantity first in the first loop. Then in the second loop accumulate price * (quantity / totalQuantity).

Comment: Then the OP may have underflow instead of overflow.