# BigDecimal with minimal 2 fraction digits

Tags: java, currency, tostring, bigdecimal

I saw [Using BigDecimal to work with currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359817/using-bigdecimal-to-work-with-currencies) but I have a little different problem.

I give object with BigDecimal parameters to PDF generation library and I can't use Formatter, only send objects. Is possible that default toString method always writes BigDecimal objects in format *.xx w.g 134.40 ?

I use setScale but it doesn't work for e.g. 134.300 because it writes 134.3 instead of 134.30

Comment: What it gave when you tried ??

Comment: Have you tried this - `yourBigDecimal.SetScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you have forgotten that BigDecimal is immutable and setScale doesn't alter the existing BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal decimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(134.4);
BigDecimal decimal2 = decimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(decimal2);
```

prints

```
134.40
```

BTW to do the same thing with `double`

```
double d = 134.4;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(n)` and pass the resulting string to the PDF generation library.