# How to save and calculate Dollers in Android application

Tags: java, android, floating-point, double, decimal

I have to perform operation on Money(basically dollars). I have to get the price of a product then multiply with the Quantity and in a same way do the transactions.

Currently i am using the **double** and at some places **float** to perform operations on amount. They give me output like 13.789689 but i need only up to 2 digits. So that i have applied

```
String value = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", 13.789689);
```

to get that upto 2 digits. But now the problem is results are not coming accurate. 
Also i am to saving the Transactions information into the database and that shows variations in Cash and CC trans. 
I am So frustrated by this because it's operation with money and i am loosing that. Please guide me what to best in that case.

Comment: You should never use floating-point numbers with money because you can get rounding errors. Instead, use an integer type (usually `long`) to represent the smallest fraction (e.g., US cents) and reformat for display.

Comment: @chrylis then what is the best way to save dollars and perform calculations on it

Comment: Don't save dollars. Save cents, which are exact, and use a `long`.

Comment: rule of thumb, do not use `float` or `double` for currencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing specific to android. In Java, it is recommended that all the monetary calculations are to be carried out by `BigDecimal` data type so that there will not be any rounding off issues that you would face in `float` and `double`

Here are the few links that might help you [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359817/using-bigdecimal-to-work-with-currencies),[2](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13),[3](http://java-performance.info/bigdecimal-vs-double-in-financial-calculations/).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `float` or `double` for anything money related, if you need exact results (and you probably do). Try [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: `BigDecimal` will probably work, but it's quite expensive to deal with. `Long` is usually plenty.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is not exact when you convert dollars to euros or when you compute the monthly interest for an annual percentage rate or need any calculation other than simple addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Long is not exact for those operations either. BigDecimal arithmetic does have what is needed in practice, means to enforce the appropriate rounding rule for each inexact calculation. Long only supports truncation, which is rarely appropriate.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: My comment does not address the merits of `long` versus `BigDouble`. It addresses a fault in this answer. This answer suggests that `BigDecimal` should be used if exact results are needed. That is misleading and should be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DecimalFormat` for this , i.e.

```
    Double d=13.789689
    DecimalFormat deciFor= new DecimalFormat("##.##");
    String value=deciFor.format(d);
```

Result value will be 13.79